# Error:java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, informatica

I am running a mapping using informatica Developer tool. When i run my mapping in dev environment it works fine, where as when i try to read from prod and write to Dev it fails.

Difference between Dev & Prod Source Hive Table. 
Dev table DDL doesn't use any Serde file where as prod does.

Ex: Prod DDL

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE kbb_moat_viewability_inventory
(column_1 string COMMENT 'from deserializer',
column_2 string COMMENT 'from deserializer',
column_50 string COMMENT 'from deserializer') 
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'com.bizo.hive.serde.csv.CSVSerde'
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION 'hdfs://nameservice1/some/location/folder';
```

Please have look at the Hadoop job log and explain me what's happening and what should be done to fix this issue.

Please let me know, if you need more information. Any help is greatly appreciated :)

```
2015-06-30 18:16:09,367 FATAL [IPC Server handler 3 on 16068] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskAttemptListenerImpl: Task: attempt_1428497227446_121614_m_000019_0 - exited : java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:109)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:75)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:426)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:342)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:167)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1554)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:162)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:106)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:109)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:75)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.configure(MapRunner.java:38)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:106)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Map operator initialization failed
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecMapper.configure(ExecMapper.java:134)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class com.bizo.hive.serde.csv.CSVSerde not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.getConvertedOI(MapOperator.java:314)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.setChildren(MapOperator.java:333)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecMapper.configure(ExecMapper.java:103)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class com.bizo.hive.serde.csv.CSVSerde not found
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:1803)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.getConvertedOI(MapOperator.java:284)
    ... 24 more
```

Comment: Facing the same issue. Surprised to see there are no answers for this. Seems like a common issue.